# LvCharts.Wpf - How to update label values (redraw labels)

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Trying to get a hang on framework called Live Charts. I'm reading my values and labels from MS SQL database. The first time it reads values everything is shown. I've added a new event when I select another item from a list it updates query and brings other values.

The problem is when I bring other values my Labels don't renew. Now I debugged and variables contain everything as expected but Label values don't update. Maybe there is some command to force update on chart so that I can redraw labels?

Labels are binding to a variable

```
<lvc:Axis x:Name="axisX"
          FontFamily="Arial" 
          Foreground="Black" 
          FontSize="10" 
          MinValue="0" 
          MaxValue="9" 
          LabelsRotation="25" 
          Title="" 
          Labels="{Binding Labels}">
```

I update all values and push to chart

```
public void ChartDraw()
{
   Labels = new[] { "" };
   Labels = Str.ToArray(); //Labels get values from MS SQL, values are correct.
   DataContext = this;

   YFormatter = value => value + " %";

   foreach (string sqlread in Sql_Koncentracija)
   {
      SeriesCollection[0].Values.Add(Convert.ToDouble(sqlread)); // this adds values to //chart and it updates automatically, but labels dont update.
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your DataContext binding value in loading or in class constructor:

```
...
public YourClass() { 
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; 
}
```

or if you need init data context after loading set your context after  your control/form loaded :

```
public YourClass() { 
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += (s, e) => {
                this.DataContext = this; ;
            };
}
```

Comment: I already had DataContext = this; in Public MainWindow(). Where exactly i need to put it? I tried to put this.Loaded in various places but it does nothing.

Comment: @user3524910:  based on your data post has been edited

Answer (score 0):

For people looking in the future here is how i solved it.

```
DataContext = Labels;
DataContext = this;
```

add these two lines. If i added only DataContext = labels; Chart would not even draw.

Answer (score -2):

```
    DataContext = Labels;
    DataContext = this;
```

Above is available in c# to me. THX!

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it more clear.